# how to move the data in the table cell to another table cell in swift?

Tags: swift4

I don't speak English well. Please answer easily. 
I am making notes in swift. but there are some problems.
I want to make the Recycle Bin function like Window.
So I want to move the data in the table `cell(Main.View)` to another table `cell(TrashCan.View)`.

[image]

Click the icon next to the label in the main view to open a window that asks you to delete it.
if I want to delete it, that data in a table `cell(Main.View)` move to another table `cell(TrahshCan.View)`

```
 @IBAction func actionSheet(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let lockAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Lock", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    }

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        print("delete")
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if (segue.identifier == "targetSegue"){
                let trashView : TrashCan = segue.destination as! TrashCan
                trashView.MemoData = self.MemoData
            }
        }
    } // Main의 delete는 지우기가 아닌 휴지통으로 이동을 의미함

    let cancelButtonAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel)


    alertController.addAction(lockAction)
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButtonAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this code is Action sheet in `Main.View`(Three rows of triples icon)

and next is `TrashCan.View`(Recycle Bin)

```
import UIKit

class TrashCan: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var trashView: UITableView!

var MemoData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let MemoData = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "MemoData") {
        print(MemoData)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// MARK : Table
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    MemoData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MemoData") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    return MemoData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TrashCell

    MemoData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MemoData") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    Cell.TitleLabel.text = MemoData[indexPath.row]

    return Cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let MemoNumber = indexPath.row
    UserDefaults.standard.set(MemoNumber, forKey: "MemoNumber")

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToRecord", sender: self)
}
// Table_End

@IBAction func trashList(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let moveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    } // Main으로 복원

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    } // 완전삭제

    let cancelButtonAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel)


    alertController.addAction(moveAction)
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButtonAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

How do I fix these? please, help me T.T

Comment: Why you get MemoData from NSUserDefaults in TrushCan class? You already pass MemoData from MainView. Use that variable and use.

Comment: This is the first project, so it lacks understanding of Swift.

Comment: see my answer below and try. Comment if you have any problem of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already passed MemoData in trashView object class. Now you need to use that MemoData and show on trashView.

Update:
First store memo data to UserDefault. Update code from here

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "targetSegue"){
            let trashView : TrashCan = segue.destination as! TrashCan
            trashView.MemoData = self.MemoData
          UserDefaults.standard.set(self.MemoData, forKey: "MemoData")
        }
    }
```

Now get "MemoData" from UserDefault and show on TrashView

```
@IBOutlet weak var trashView: UITableView!

var MemoData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

 if let MemoData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "MemoData")) {
    print(MemoData)
}

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// MARK : Table
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -
> Int {
    return MemoData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {

    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TrashCell
    Cell.TitleLabel.text = MemoData[indexPath.row]

   return Cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    let MemoNumber = indexPath.row
    UserDefaults.standard.set(MemoNumber, forKey: "MemoNumber")

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToRecord", sender: self)
}
// Table_End

@IBAction func trashList(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let moveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

 } // Main으로 복원

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

  } // 완전삭제

    let cancelButtonAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel)


    alertController.addAction(moveAction)
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButtonAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

This will help.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, press the Delete button to print the "delete". and When I press the Recycle Bin icon, the " [] sign appears in the window. Unfortunately, our team members decided to abandon this function. Although the problem has not been resolved, we feel grateful for your help.

Comment: @pyj Finally I got the issue. I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I tried again. But the result was the same. Unfortunately, we gave up this function entirely.
But thank you so much for helping us!!! It's okay that you try not to resolve this problem.

Comment: okay. I want to know one thing. self.MemoData is an Array or String?

Comment: it is String array. Not String. Not Array.